# MPMoviePlayerViewController on iPad view Landscape

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, landscape

I have a view and a MPMoviePlayerViewController.. the iPad is oriented in landscape left mode, but when I play the video, the video is good to see in portrait mode...
is there a way to force movieplayer to rotate in landscape mode?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can force a MPMoviePlayerViewcontroller to work in landscapce mode by

```
[player setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

You can read my blog entry for sample code http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/play-video-on-iphone-and-ipad/

Comment: thanks Saurabh! 
I read yesterday your blog ( I poosted also ) but the line where shows this thing I skipped, I don't know how!!!!!

Thanks, I'll try soon!

Comment: sorry, but the MPMMoviePlayerViewController doesn't have setOrientation method...
https://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 4):

```
@interface MyMovieViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController
@end

@implementation MyMovieViewController
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

@end
```

Then just instantiate MyMovieViewController instead of MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Comment: Don't forget to add #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h> above @interface.